# Как прижать два слова по разным краям элемента?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Как можно создать конструкцию типа

```
|левая сторона                                      правая сторона|
```

Тут знак "|" обозначает соответственно левую и правую границы элемента

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; text-align: right">  
    <span style="float: left">левая сторона</span>  
    правая сторона 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все верно.

Answer (score 1):

Чисто посмеяться, пример "грязного хака", встречал лично.

Внимание, **не пользуйтесь кроме крайних случаев** (такие очень редко, но бывают).

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; overflow: hidden; text-align: justify;">  
<span style="display: inline-block;">левая&nbsp;сторона</span> <span style="display: inline-block;">правая&nbsp;сторона</span> <span style="letter-spacing: 5000px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: СильнО! =)